# Mouse hover character limit in IE

Tags: html, jsp

Does anyone know if IE has a maximum length that can be displayed in a hover? (I guess 512). I am working on a application where on mouse hovering on a image it should displays description and it is excluding the characters if it exceeds 512. It works fine in Chrome, but IE truncates the hover text. 
Can anyone please help me how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Best Regards,
Srinivas.

Comment: For me IE shows upto 488 chars and chrome 960 chars...

Comment: If you mean the display of the value of a `title` attribute, you should say that explicitly in the question. You should also consider using some more reasonable way of showing text on mouseover, at least for anything more that a few dozen characters.

Comment: Yes I am talking about the "Title" attribute. Is it possible to increase the number of characters to display on mouse hover?